# Synonym for "share the love" in terms of sharing information?

Tags: phrases

I'm trying to find a catch phrase that will entice customers to make referrals.  We want them to "share the love" they have for our services with others, but I want it to sound professional.

Comment: Pay it forward?

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" phrase probably depends on your business, what it does, what brand it's going for, etc. But the phrase "spread the word" comes to mind, and you can use that to start searching online thesauri for the exact phrase you're looking for.

Comment: My thoughts exactly!  That's why "share the love" didn't seem appropriate.  "Spread the word" fits much better, but I would prefer a phrase that isn't as widely used.  I've been looking through thesauri, but the phrase doesn't generate results.  Only "sharing" by itself works.  I'll keep trying!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You might ask (as simple as that) for [referrals](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/referrals) with "Referrals Welcome" or "Refer a Friend".

Answer (score 0):

"pay it forward" may work depending on the business.